# Remove old successful job on Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In dataflow of Google Cloud when you run a job the effect of that job will remain for a long time. We want to remove any remaining effect of that job in the list of dataflow jobs.

How we can delete an old job from dataflow list?

Comment: This isn't currently possible; Although there's a public issue where you can track the progress on it, here: https://issuetracker.google.com/110798648